# Выбор из большого списка элементов на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html5, bootstrap, mobile

Вопрос в том, что использовать для отображения большого списка элементов на мобильном устройстве, так чтобы это было удобно для пользователя?

И есть ли готовые кроссбраузерные решения?

Верстка сайта на `Bootstrap 2.3.2`

> Речь про выпадающий список или подобные элементы.

Comment: возможно вам подойдет [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: @Ruslan_K По большому счету это тот же Chosen, а хочется как то более функционально, например группировка и отображение не только в один столбец а в несколько если того позволяет размер экрана устройства.